# How to create compressed iso file system like official Ubuntu isos

Tags: iso

I am trying to create a custom Ubuntu based distro but I can't figure out how to create compressed iso file system.

Answer (score 2):

You use squashfs

The instructions are on the wiki pages :

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization#Assembling_the_file_system

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch#Compress_the_chroot