# Creating .iso file - which uses only used disk space

Tags: 18.04, iso, disk-image

We would like to create an image of one of our existing VMs (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS).

The disk space of VM is 50GB.

Used space is 8GB.

When I am creating an .iso file of this VM, the size of the .iso file is coming to 50GB.

Is it possible to create an iso file of size 8GB (only used space) from this VM?

Comment: you will need squashfs for that. https://askubuntu.com/questions/446481/how-to-create-compressed-iso-file-system-like-official-ubuntu-isos  It is basically the  same Canonical used to do to compress the installer to fit on a DVD.

Comment: This one is a better read https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31669/is-it-possible-to-mount-a-gzip-compressed-dd-image-on-the-fly/75590#75590

Comment: If you move the VM to vmWARE, you can just perform a regular clone operation and the disk will automatically be converted to thin provisioned. Both VmWare workstation and VSphere will perform this operation. May be an easier route for you. Here's a link with an explanation: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1017514